# separate indexes for select optimization

Tags: sqlite

I have a table 'data' with columns
id (auto_increment)   id_device (integer)    timestamp(numeric)

I need to execute these selects:

```
select * from data where id<10000000 and id_device=345
or
select * from data where id<10000000 and id_device=345 and timestamp>'2017-01-01 10:00:00' and timestamp<'2017-03-01 08:00:00'
```

**For first select:**
Is it better to make separate index for "id" and separate for "id_device"?
Or is it better for performance to make index like INDEX id, id_device?

**For second select:**
Is better to make separate index for "id" and separate for "id_device" and separate for "timestamp"?
Or is it better for performance to make index like INDEX id, id_device, timestamp?

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it, but I don't understand if I should CREATE INDEX idx1 ON data(id, id_device); or better separate index for id (which is autoincrement already), and separate for id_device, and separate for timestamp?

Comment: Both coices would not be optimal. Also see the [indexing tutorial](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html). When in doubt, use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Nice. But what is optimal for these queries?

Comment: Answer: it depends! It depends on your data. On the cardinality of your columns id and id_device. That is, how many distinct different values do you have in id and in id_device. And your query also uses < for id and = for id_device. This suggests to me that separating out on id_device is most important to do first, before id<10000000, although I cannot know for sure i

Comment: I am experimenting with EXPLAIN. Thanks for learning me something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short answer: it depends on your data.

Longer: if id_device=345 is true for fewer rows than id<10000000 then id_device should be listed first in a multi-column index: ...ON data(id_device,id). Also if select speed is more important to you/your users than insert/update/delete speed, then why not add a lot of indexes and leave it to the query planner to choose which ones to use:

```
create index i01_tbl on tbl(id);
create index i02_tbl on tbl(id_device);
create index i03_tbl on tbl(timestamp);
create index i04_tbl on tbl(id,id_device);
create index i05_tbl on tbl(id_device,id);
create index i06_tbl on tbl(timestamp,id);
create index i07_tbl on tbl(id,timestamp);
create index i08_tbl on tbl(id_device,timestamp);
create index i09_tbl on tbl(timestamp,id_device);
create index i10_tbl on tbl(id, id_device, timestamp);
create index i11_tbl on tbl(id_device, id, timestamp);
create index i12_tbl on tbl(id_device, timestamp, id);
create index i13_tbl on tbl(id, timestamp, id_device);
create index i14_tbl on tbl(timestamp, id_device, id);
create index i15_tbl on tbl(timestamp, id, id_device);
```

The query planner algorithms in your database (sqlite have them too) usually make good choises on that. Especially if you run the ANALYZE sqlite command periodically or after changing lots of data. The downside of having many indexes is slower inserts and deletes (and updates if they involve indexed columns) and more disk/memory usage. Use explain plan on your important SQLs (important when it comes to speed) to check which indexes are used and not. If an index is never used or only used in queries that is fast anyway without it, then you can drop those. Also be aware that newer versions of your database (sqlite, oracle, postgresql) can have newer query planner algorithms which for most SELECTs are better, but for some can get worse. Realistic tests on realistic datasets are the best way to tell. Which indexes to create is not an exact science and dont have definitive rules that fits all cases.

Comment: I am experimenting with EXPLAIN. Thanks for learning me something!

Comment: The best thanks in stackoverflow is to press the up-arrow above the 0 number in the left margin ;-)